# Configuration Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I need to compile kernel linux 3.4.4. I use "make menuconfig" to have a user-friendly interface to choose configuration.

I haven't understood an aspect of the kernel configuration: what is the difference between i choose to include an option during the configuration and i choose to include, as a module, an option during the configuration?

Thanks

Comment: if it is compiled as a module, it will not be inside the kernel compiled (vmlinuz), if i remind well.

Answer (score 3):

When compiled as a module, the code of that feature/component is built as a separate file, as know as kernel module, separating from the kernel's main image. To use the feature, you have to load it into the kernel with commands like `modprobe` or `insmod`. Of course you can later unload this module, to remove the feature/component. The kernel modules are normally placed at `/lib/modules/{uname -r}` on your system.

While compiled as 'y' means the code will be compiled into the main kernel image, which will be always available when the kernel is loaded and running.

Comment: the files are in `/lib/modules/\`uname -r\``.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanks, added the location.

Comment: If module has a reference into device tree or it has dependencies in mdules*.* it is automatically loaded.